# How to add subdirectory in flutter web?

Tags: flutter

I want to create a shop web application with flutter. I need to add the subdirectory to the URL of the app. For example, if my app address is `https://example.app/`, then I want to add `https://example.app/500` that 500 is one of my product IDs. How can I do that and how to detect that id?

Answer (score 0):

Recently we developed one web app in Flutter. In that we were managing category with product id.

For that I have used [**`auto_route: ^3.1.3`**](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route) dependency.

Here is the sample, How you can create routes.

```
class UserRoute extends PageRouteInfo {        
   UserRoute({List<PagerouteInfo> children}) :        
    super(        
         name,         
         path: '/user/:id',        
         initialChildren: children);        
  static const String name = 'UserRoute';        
}
```

Check documentation for more info.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it is using `navigator 2`. You need to extend `RouteInformationParser` and check `pathSegments`.

On your main class, `App` will return `MaterialApp.router` and need to provide `routerDelegate` and `routeInformationParser`.

```dart
 return MaterialApp.router(
      routeInformationParser: _routeInformationParser,
      routerDelegate: _routerDelegate,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
    );
```

`_routeInformationParser` will be extended from `RouteInformationParser` and `_routerDelegate` will extend `RouterDelegate`.

Based on `https://example.app/500` it is having `pathSegments.length == 2`

If will be handled like

```dart
   if (uri.pathSegments.length == 2) {
      if (uri.pathSegments[0] != 'details') return AppRoutePath.unknown();// recheck

      final id = int.tryParse(uri.pathSegments[1]);
      if (id == null) return AppRoutePath.unknown();
      return AppRoutePath.details(id);
    }
```

You can find my practice demo [here](https://github.com/yeasin50/Dart_-Flutter_Advanced/blob/master/lib/navigator2/demo1.dart) using navigator2. Also there are great packages for it like, auto_route as @Pratik Butani described , [go_router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) etc.

Answer (score 0):

As others said you can use some package like auto_route or etc. I use the [Getx](https://pub.dev/packages/get) package for state manager and it also has navigation with named routes. You can use [dynamic URLs links](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/master/documentation/en_US/route_management.md#dynamic-urls-links) and do what you want easily.